# Retrieving data for shiny-server config

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

In `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` I have an [SSL configuration](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#ssl) that looks like:

```
server {
  # ...
  ssl /etc/path/to/ssl-key.pem /etc/path/to/ssl.cert;
  # ...
}
```

Now, from an R REPL on the server on which Shiny Server is running, I'm curious if there's a way to *retrieve* the configuration data from `shiny-server.conf` through any sort of (semi-) official API.

Something like:

```
# server.R
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
   # ... ?
})
```

That will yield something to the effective of:

```
"ssl": ["/etc/path/to/ssl-key.pem", "/etc/path/to/ssl.cert"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get access to that, to be honest, as it might be a security risk to allow apps (and therefore "regular users") to see configuration items. (It might include secrets for SAML/LDAP/... configuration for instance.)

Now I don't know that this answer will solve that problem, it might enable you to find what you need instead.

Note: I intentionally filter out several types of objects within `session`, as I've found that either they crash (they're complex compound objects, perhaps who-knows-what in them) or they're obviously just extraneous. One could possibly `saveRDS` this to a file and retrieve it from the server if you want to get more visibility to internals being filtered out.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  h3("Parsed query string"),
  verbatimTextOutput("queryText"),
  h3("URL components"),
  verbatimTextOutput("sessionText"),
  h3("EnvVars"),
  verbatimTextOutput("envvarText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Parse the GET query string
  output$queryText <- renderText({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    # Return a string with key-value pairs
    paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse=", ")
  })
  # Return the components of the URL in a string:
  output$sessionText <- renderText({
    cls <- sapply(session, function(a) class(a)[1])
    nms <- names(cls[ cls %in% c("list", "character", "numeric", "integer", "NULL", "logical", "environment") ])
    nms <- setdiff(nms, ".__enclos_env__")
    paste(
      capture.output(
        str(
          sapply(nms,
                 function(sessnm) {
                   if (inherits(session[[sessnm]], c("environment", "reactivevalues"))) {
                     sapply(names(session[[sessnm]]), function(nm) session[[sessnm]][[nm]], simplify = FALSE)
                   } else if (inherits(session[[sessnm]], c("character", "numeric", "integer"))) {
                     session[[sessnm]]
                   } else class(session[[sessnm]])
                 }, simplify = FALSE),
          nchar.max = 1e5,
          vec.len = 1e5
        )
      ),
      collapse = "\n"
    )
  })
  # Dump the environment variables
  output$envvarText <- renderText({
    paste(
      capture.output(
        str(as.list(Sys.getenv()))
      ),
      collapse = "\n"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This renders something like this (with some privacy blocked out, and fuzzy in general since, well, your results my differ depending on your specific server.

[image]

This is on RStudio Connect v1.8.2, hosted on Ubuntu 16.04. The authentication is via SAML; other auth methods might have slightly different (more or less) fields.

Comment: Regarding "I don't think you can get access to that, to be honest, as it might be a security risk" - I don't disagree.  In this case the app uses a keypair to make a request from another rest service.  Would you suggest the app simply use its own keypair separate from that used by shiny server?

Comment: I think you're asking if your shiny app should either (a) reuse the secret/public key pair used by the shiny server, or (b) generate its own. I would absolutely choose the second option, generate your own keypair. If its private key is compromised, you have to reset the keypair for the app. If the private key for the shiny server itself is compromised, a lot more "bad" can happen. (I don't know the complexity or power of your REST service, so ... ymmv.) Does this make sense? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes, makes (common) sense ;)